# can't traverse string with iterators: however my version with indices does work

Tags: c++, string, stl, iterator

I'm writing a small program which converts all occurrences of positive integers into binary integers. So how do I write this:

I have a function numbersToBinary which takes a string and modifies it so it will contain numbers in binary form instead of decimal one.

```
void numbersToBinary(string &src)
{
   for (string::iterator iter = src.begin(); iter != src.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (isdigit(*iter))
        {
           string::iterator numberStart = iter++; //numberStart = iter;
            while ((iter != src.end()) && (isdigit(*iter)))
            {
                iter++;
            }
            string ins = decimalToBinary(string(numberStart, iter));
            src.replace(numberStart, iter, ins);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that this function catches an exception in replace method when called with string that ends with numbers.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pashazz/1df366842c765d86f24d): with code which you could also see here: [github](https://github.com/pashazz/replacer). Unit-tests are available

MWE:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string example = "String123Primer";
    numbersToBinary(example);
    cout << example << endl;  //"String1111011Primer
    return 0;
}
```

Function that actually does work:

```
void numbersToBinary(string &src)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); ++i)
      {
         if (isdigit(src[i]))
           {
              int numberStart = i++; //numberStart = iter;
              while (src.length() != i && (isdigit(src[i])))
              { 
                  ++i;
              }
              string ins = decimalToBinary(src.substr(numberStart, i-numberStart));
              src.replace(numberStart, i-numberStart, ins);
          }
         }

      }
```

EDIT: I've created a new version of this function:

```
void numbersToBinary(string &src) {
    string newString;
    for (string::iterator iter = src.begin(); iter != src.end(); iter++) {
        if (isdigit(*iter)) {
            string::iterator numberStart = iter++; //numberStart = iter;
            while ((iter != src.end()) && (isdigit(*iter))) {
                iter++;
            }
            string ins = decimalToBinary(string(numberStart, iter));
            newString.append(ins);
        }
        else
            newString.push_back(*iter);

    }
    src = newString;
}
```

But it turns out that condition (iter != src.end()) is never false, even when I'm coming to the end of string:

```
    Breakpoint 2, numbersToBinary (src="My favourite number is13and nevermind 13") at /home/pasha/projects/miem/Replacer/func.cpp:58
    58                  newString.append(ins);
    (gdb) print ins
    $40 = "1101"
    (gdb) s
    51          for (string::iterator iter = src.begin(); iter != src.end(); iter++) {
    (gdb) print iter
    $41 = 0 '\000'
    (gdb) s
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>::operator++ (this=0x7fffffffd7d0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:757
    757           { return __normal_iterator(_M_current++); }
    (gdb) s
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>::__normal_iterator (this=0x7fffffffd780, __i=@0x7fffffffd788: 0x6a1a10 "") at /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:729
    729           : _M_current(__i) { }
    (gdb) s
    __gnu_cxx::operator!=<char*, std::string> (__lhs=16 '\020', __rhs=0 '\000') at /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:832
    832         { return __lhs.base() != __rhs.base(); }
    (gdb) s
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>::base (this=0x7fffffffd7d0) at /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:794
    794           { return _M_current; }
    (gdb) s
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>::base (this=0x7fffffffd810) at /usr/include/c++/4.9.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:794
    794           { return _M_current; }
    (gdb) s
    numbersToBinary (src="My favourite number is13and nevermind 13") at /home/pasha/projects/miem/Replacer/func.cpp:52
    52              if (isdigit(*iter)) {
    (gdb) print iter
    $42 = 16 '\020'
    (gdb) print src.end()
    $43 = 0 '\000'
```

EDIT: Incredibly, if I add this

```
if (iter == src.end()) break;
```

before end of for loop, it works! What is this???

Comment: Iterators can be invalidated with a call to `std::string::replace`.

Comment: You should create a new `result` string and return it

Comment: the matter is that there could be more than one integer in a string. How could I deal with this? I certainly need to continue the loop after calling `replace`

Comment: you might just be better off using `[]` operator instead (array indexing)...things will be a little less hairy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the updated (and ... *updated*.) code...

> EDIT: Incredibly, if I add this
>
> ```
> if (iter == src.end()) break;
> ```
>
> before end of for loop, it works! What is this???

Its not incredible. Thats how for-loops work. You need to understand when the *increment* step of a for-loop is executed vs. when the *conditional* step is evaluated.

The conditional eval is done **before** a loop body is (re)entered. The increment step is done **after** a loop body is complete, *before* the return to the top of the loop for the next conditional eval.

In short, your for-loop increment step is incrementing an iterator that is already at the end of the sequence if your inner digit loop ran it to `src.end()`. Remember, the for-loop increment is done after each iteration is done, but before the next conditional test.

Therefore,

```
void numbersToBinary(string &src)
{
    string newString;
    string::iterator iter = src.begin();
    while (iter != src.end())
    {
        if (isdigit(*iter))
        {
            string::iterator numberStart = iter++; //numberStart = iter;
            while ((iter != src.end()) && (isdigit(*iter))) {
                ++iter;
            }
            string ins = decimalToBinary(string(numberStart, iter));
            newString.append(ins);
        }
        else
        {
            newString.push_back(*iter++);
        }

    }
    src = newString;
}
```

is one of *several* ways to do what you're attempting. You could also stick a hard-break at the end of the loop if  `iter` has arrived at `src.end()` (though it seems somewhat redundant to check there, as we already know where it was set to `src.end()` : the digit loop.)

Answer (score 0):

After you call `replace`, the original string value no longer exists. So iterators to parts of it are no longer valid. When you loop again, `iter` is an iterator to part of a value that no longer exists, so comparing it to `end`, the end of a different value entirely, makes no sense. After you call `replace`, you need to set `iter` to the correct new value in the new string before you compare it to `end`.